# Best practice to store and retrieve localstorage data in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular5, angular-local-storage

I don't know whether I can ask or not this question here, because this site is to ask about programming questions. but still asking.

Is there any best practice in angular 5 to store and retrieve localstorage data in angular 5. I mean like creating service or seperate class to localstorage.

I want a suggestion like accessing localstorage data in generic way from any class like using service. I mean best practice to access localstorage.

Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

`localStorage` is a global object which is available to you by default. Which means that you can use it anywhere in your code where you want to retrieve or store data in local storage.

You do not have to create a separate service just for retrieving/fetching from local storage.

It stores key/value pairs and both should be of type string. It's perfectly valid if you use like this in your typescript.

```
//to set
localStorage.setItem('key', strValue);

//to get
strValue: string = localStorage.getItem('key');
```

Comment: Hi bitscanbyte, thank you for your response. but I know how to store and retrieve localstorage data. I want a suggestion like accessing localstorage data in generic way from any class like using service.

Comment: As it's a global object, you can use it anywhere, it doesn't have to be a service, meaning you don't have to use constructor params to inject localStorage object. It cannot be any more generic that using it like `localStorage.get('key')` as you only need to pass the key, and use it in any class.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @bitscanbyte answer from the angular's perspective; you could use a service methods to get, set particular item without having to remember or mention item key or parse / stringify JSON every time.

For example 'User':

```
//User service
getUser(){
  let user = localStorage.getItem('user');
  return JSON.parse(user);
}

setUser(user){
  localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
}
```

Now you can just call service.getUser() and service.setUser(user) functions in your component.